# Can a dart2native executable be published on AppStore and MicrosoftStore?

Tags: dart, dart2native

We are looking into building some apps with Flutter for desktop.

We know it is in beta or alpha stage, however, as our app is relatively simple, we may be able to use Flutter now.

However, reading here and there I am not sure if it will be possible to publish the app to the Apple OSX Store and Microsoft Windows Store.

Is it possible to sign and publish the dart2native binary to these stores?

Also, can it be executed without setting custom permissions?
In OSX some apps needs the user o go to the System Settings and enable the app to be opened.

We can't have that.

Comment: You should read here about the app signing https://dart.dev/tools/dart2native#known-limitations

Comment: oh, flutter desktop does not use dart2native, so we shouldn't have problems with signing from what I've seen in the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought Flutter used dart2native or shared its logic to build desktop apps. But it is not the case, so yes, the app can be shared in stores.